# Using pthread.h on a windows build

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I have a codebase that makes extensive use of pthread.h.  On a windows visual studio project, this obviously doesn't work since pthreads is a unix utility.

I know there exists pthread-win32 or something of the sort, but is there a way to have a codebase use this, without replacing all of the pthread code?

edit: I'd prefer to not have to go through and replace all the pthread calls.  This is my question

Comment: I don't understand. You say you know that a pthread library exists for win32, so why don't you use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/. While I've never used that particular library, I've had luck using some windows ports/abstraction layers of POSIX APIs.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend boost as a library that contains a platform-independent thread abstraction. I don't think you'll find any attempt to call the pthread functions themselves to be satisfying. It's also not very hard to map pthread to Win32 for yourself.

Comment: Not very useful for someone who has an existing code base using pthreads where they'd prefer not having to rewrite the threading code though. :)

Comment: I've done it many times. Global search/replace was invented for a reason.

Comment: That reason was not switching between APIs with potential semantic differences.

Comment: This answer is off topic. If you're having problem with a screw you shouldn't go about changing the whole car to whatever new screw you could find.

Answer (score 3):

If the code is very heavily *nix-based, you'll probably have the best luck compiling it with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)+GCC.  If pthreads is the only *nix dependency and you'd like to avoid the Cygwin dependency, then you should go with [Pthreads-win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/).