# Windows thread with C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I saw this question [Simple example of threading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c)
but my problem is that I want to run this program in windows 32 and it seems that pthread is not recognized in windows!please tell me what is problem?This is my error:
fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?(I added #include "StdAfx.h but it still
 does not work!)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
  long tid;
  tid = (long)threadid;
  printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc;
  long t;
  for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
  {
  printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
  rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
  if (rc){
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
         }
  }

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
   }
```

Comment: I added #include "StdAfx.h" but still it does not recognized pthread!

Comment: What's the error now you've included "StdAfx.h"?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170038/using-pthread-h-on-a-windows-build

Comment: fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?

Comment: and the other is fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because threads are architecture dependent concept, you won't be able to use pthread without using some kind of a wrapper or use windows-specific threading functions.

You have three choices

1. Use pthread-win32 (wrapper for Win32 thread functions :http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/ )
2. Use Windows specific threading functions with #ifdef _WIN32 #else #endif wrapped around
3. Use boost thread library

EDIT: for C1010 error follow the above answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to your compiler error:

> fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for
>   precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to
>   your source?

...the problem has nothing to do with pthreads.  It has to do with [precompiled header files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

You can either:

1. Turn off using precompiled header files in your project.  Project>Settings>C/C++>Precompiled Headers
2. Do as the error suggests, and add `#include "stdafx.h"` as the first line in the CPP file

Comment: It's very important that it be the VERY FIRST line of the .cpp file.

Comment: @ John: sorry I can't vote up your answer but I really appreciate it:)